# Which one is correct: "I'm average in height", "I'm average height" or "I'm an average height"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Could you tell me which one is correct:

- *I'm average in height*
- *I'm average height*
- *I'm an average height*

meaning I'm neither tall nor short.

Comment: They're all fine, as is *I'm **of** average height,* and doubtless others. Don't waste time and effort trying to identify the "best" stylistic choice to make here. Make it easy on yourself and stick with whichever version sounds best to you. You probably want the version closest to the equivalent in your own native tongue (which should be easier to "remember", but if it's your "natural" choice you'll always make the same decision anyway, so you don't even need to remember it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm average in height
- I'm average height

Either of these is acceptable, perhaps the latter is a little more informal. You can also say "I'm **of** average height", although this is perhaps the most formal of all.

- I'm an average height

This isn't idiomatic. Saying "I'm **an** average" height suggests that there are many averages. True, "average height" is normally within a *range* determined by age, gender etc, but your height is either average or it is not and this just sounds vague. It's okay in other contexts though - you might say "I'm an average piano player".